# How to remove diagonal plot from pairplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I used

`g=sns.pairplot(df,hue="Class")`

to do pairplot as shown in the picture. How do I get rid of diagonal plots?

[image: Click here to show Pairplot Picture]

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with was to hide the lines and shaded areas of the plot by passing appropriate [`diag_kws`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html). The plot still happens, it’s just for all intents and purposes invisible:

```
g = sns.pairplot(df, hue="Class",
    diag_kind="kde",
    diag_kws={"linewidth": 0, "shade": False})
```

Comment: I tried, it still displays the diagonal graphs. Thank you though!

Comment: @Carolineontheway Serves me right for throwing things out based on the documentation without trying them first. Try my updated answer though, that works for me, even though I find the solution very unsatisfactory,

Answer (score 0):

`grid.diag_axes` only contains [twins to the original axes](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/axisgrid.py#L1452-L1455), so hiding those is not enough. `grid.axes` does contain the original `axes`, that can be hidden with `set_visible(False)`.

```py
for i, y_var in enumerate(g.y_vars):
    for j, x_var in enumerate(g.x_vars):
        if x_var == y_var:
            g.axes[i, j].set_visible(False)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try this :

```
def hide_current_axis(*args, **kwds):
    plt.gca().set_visible(False)

g.map_diag(hide_current_axis)
```

Comment: This does not work, as the `func` provided to `map_diag` only ever sees a [twin of the axis](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/eb2b5a21dfc9a20f2eeec100490d5c014e689c65/seaborn/axisgrid.py#L1452-L1455). `[g.axes[i, j].set_visible(False) for j, x_var in enumerate(g.x_vars) for i, y_var in enumerate(g.y_vars) if x_var == y_var]` will thus do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentations of pairplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) you can just use the **corner=True** parameter

The code would be:

```
sns.pairplot(data=df, corner=True)
plt.show()
```